# How do I use linebreaks but keep the text inline with an image?

Tags: html, css

I want the text to be next to the dog, but when I use < br>... it goes under the dog

(dog is display: inline-block)

https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/pweOWN

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dCx2Ck/logo.png" style="display: inline-block" />
   Pet Stay<br>
   &<br>
   Vacay
</div>
```

Comment: That's because images are inline-block, they flow with text but also have width and height. The image is on the same line as the "Pet Stay" text, but on new lines for "&" and "Vacay".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `display: inline-block` is only applied to the image, and not to the accompanying text. What I would recommend is to separate out the image from the text, and give **both** `display: inline-block`:

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dCx2Ck/logo.png" alt="logo" border="0" style="display: inline-block" />
  <h1 style="display: inline-block">
    Pet Stay<br> &
    <br> Vacay
  </h1>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can make use of **floats**, which allow your content to be displayed right next to each other, and **flex** to ensure that text is vertically centralised:

```css
.text-center .left-column, .text-center .right-column {
  float: left;
  height: 175px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="left-column">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dCx2Ck/logo.png" alt="logo" border="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <h1>
      Pet Stay<br> &
      <br> Vacay
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you have your paragraph and image inside an (un-closed) `<h1`> tag, which I've removed for the purpose of my examples. `<h1>` is reserved for header text. I'm assuming you want the text to have the header styles, so I've replaced the `<p>` tags with `<h1>` tags in the examples.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap your text and use `inline-block` for the wrapper:

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dCx2Ck/logo.png" alt="logo" border="0" style="display: inline-block" />
    <div style="display: inline-block">
      Pet Stay
      <br>
      &
      <br>
      Vacay
    </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```